Image of a closed cone
I am trying to understand some convex analysis. I have the following question at hand:
Let $K \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a closed cone. A set $C\subseteq R^n$ is said to be a cone if for every $c \in C$, and any nonnegative scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, $\lambda c \in C$. A closed cone is a cone which is closed under the usual topology of $R^n$.
Let $T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ be a linear map. Is it true that $T(K)$ is closed?
I have found an example which shows that $K$ is not a cone then the image need not be closed: Let $n = 2, m = 1, T : (x, y) \mapsto x+y$ and $K = \{ (i, -i + \frac{1}{i}) : i \in \mathbb N\}$. Then, $T(K) = \{\frac{1}{i}: i \in \mathbb N\}$ which is not a closed set whereas $K$ is closed (every point of $K$ is isolated). But I am not sure how to find a counterexample for the case when $K$ is a cone or prove that the image is indeed closed. Please help.

I think the following is a counterexample: Consider $\mathbb{R}^4= \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ (the space of real $2\times 2$-matrices) and $K$ the cone of all positive semidefinite matrices (which is closed). Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{2\times2} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear mapping
$$
T\left(\begin{array}{cc}
       a&b_1\\
       b_2&c 
       \end{array}  \right)= 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       a\\
       b_1+b_2
       \end{array}\right).
$$
It is sufficent to consider $T$ for symmetric matrices. Then
$$
T\left(\begin{array}{cc}
       a&b\\
       b&c 
       \end{array}  \right)= 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       a\\
       2b
       \end{array}\right).
$$
Now
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0\\
       2 
       \end{array}\right) \in \overline{T(K)},
$$
since
$$
T\left(\begin{array}{cc}
       \varepsilon&1\\
       1&1/ \varepsilon 
       \end{array}  \right)=
 \left(\begin{array}{c}
        \varepsilon\\
       2 
       \end{array}\right) \quad ( \varepsilon>0),
$$
and since for $\varepsilon>0$ the matrices
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
       \varepsilon&1\\
       1&1/ \varepsilon 
       \end{array}  \right)
$$
are in $K$ (the eigenvalues are $0$ and $\varepsilon + 1/\varepsilon>0$).
On the other hand
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0\\
       2 
       \end{array}\right) \notin T(K),
$$
since the only symmetric matrices which are mapped to ${0 \choose 2}$ are
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
       0&1\\
       1&c 
       \end{array}  \right),
$$
and these are never positive semidefinite (one eigenvalue is $c/2-\sqrt{c^2/4+1}<0$).
EDIT: The following example is maybe more illustrative.
Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the ice-cream cone
$$
K=\{(x,y,z):z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}.
$$
Orthogonal projection in direction $(1,0,1)$ yields the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $T(x,y,z)=(y,x-z)$. Now
$$
T(t,1,\sqrt{t^2+1})=(1,t-\sqrt{t^2+1}) \to (1,0) \quad (t \to \infty), 
$$
so $(1,0)\in \overline{T(K)}$. But $(1,0)\notin T(K)$ since the vectors of the form $(t,1,t)$, $t \in\mathbb{R}$ are not in $K$.

Perfect, thank you! How did you come up with this? Could you share your thought process?

To be honest, I just recalled that I have seen such an example for the cone of psd matrices a long time ago. I couldn't remember where and how, but from there it was a matter of trying things out. I started with the matrices $[\varepsilon,1;1,1/\varepsilon]$ and tried to map them to something convergent for $\varepsilon \to 0+$.

Ah, I see, thanks again

I think I found a more illustrative example in dimension $3$. I posted it as an edit.
